# .delay() not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, css, delay, sequence, fadeout

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem, but I can't find it.

I have created a function that makes lines of text fade out sequentially, one by one, calling the `.fadeOut()` method on `.each()` element within an array.

However, when I run exactly the same code, but with the `.css()` method (to turn the text red), it changes them all at once, and not sequentially as above.

Can anyone explain why this is?

https://jsfiddle.net/v9hzpuf6/3/

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** Including code here:

```
<h1>Example 1: .fadeOut()</h1>
<h2>Works as expected...</h2>
<p class="top">line 1</p>
<p class="top">line 2</p>
<p class="top">line 3</p>
<button class="ex1">"Go"</button>

<h1>Example 2: .css()</h1>
<h2>Doesn't work as expected...</h2>
<p class="bottom">line 1</p>
<p class="bottom">line 2</p>
<p class="bottom">line 3</p>
<button class="ex2">Go</button>
```

JS:

```
$("button.ex1").on("click", function() {
  $(".top").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeOut();
  });
});

$("button.ex2").on("click", function() {
  $(".bottom").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).css("color", "red");
  });
});
```

Comment: `delay()` only affects the various queues jQuery maintains, which `css()` does not use. To achieve the effect for the `css()` method you could use a timer, either `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` would work.

Comment: Or put your code in queue https://jsfiddle.net/v9hzpuf6/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay()` only affects the various queues jQuery maintains, which `css()` does not use. To achieve the effect for the `css()` method you could use `setInterval()`. Try this:

```
$("button.ex2").on("click", function() {
    var index = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var $next = $('.bottom').eq(index++);
        if (!$next.length)
            clearInterval(timer);
        else
            $next.css('color', 'red');
    }, 400);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v9hzpuf6/7/)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery delay only works with elements in the effect queue. A quick fix is put the css function in a query function ie `.queue(function() { $(this).css("color", "red")});`:

```js
$("button.ex1").on("click", function() {
  
  $(".top").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeOut();
  
  });
});

$("button.ex2").on("click", function() {
  
  $(".bottom").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).queue(function() { $(this).css("color", "red")});
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
Example 1: .fadeOut()
</h1>
<h2>
Works as expected...
</h2>
<p class="top">line 1</p>
<p class="top">line 2</p>
<p class="top">line 3</p>
<p class="top">line 4</p>
<p class="top">line 5</p>
<p class="top">line 6</p>
<p class="top">line 7</p>
<button class="ex1">
  "Go"
</button>

<h1>
Example 2: .css()
</h1>
<h2>
Doesn't work as expected...
</h2>
<p class="bottom">line 1</p>
<p class="bottom">line 2</p>
<p class="bottom">line 3</p>
<p class="bottom">line 4</p>
<p class="bottom">line 5</p>
<p class="bottom">line 6</p>
<p class="bottom">line 7</p>
<button class="ex2">
  "Go"
</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
$("button.ex1").on("click", function() {

  $(".top").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400 * index).fadeOut();

  });
});

$("button.ex2").on("click", function() {

  $(".bottom").each(function(index) {

    $(".bottom:eq("+index+")").delay(400).css("color", "red");
  });
});
```